# std::launder do not work on gcc with -O3 option?

Tags: c++, c++17, undefined-behavior, stdlaunder

I have code snippet that, I assume, should not produce asserton failure.
But with gcc 13.2 with O3 option it fails.

So I think it is Undefined Behaviour here.
clang and gcc with O0 works fine.
And if I change destructor to some other method - assertion failure dissapears.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <new>
#include <cassert>

struct Foo
{
    ~Foo()
    {
        destructed = true;
    }

    bool destructed = false;
};

int main()
{
    alignas(alignof(Foo)) std::byte buffer[sizeof(Foo)];

    Foo* p1 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(buffer));

    new (p1) Foo();

    assert(p1->destructed == false);

    Foo* p3 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(buffer));
    p3->~Foo();
    
    //////////// Assertion failure ?????????????????????????
    assert(p3->destructed == true);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p3->destructed` is UB as the lifetime of the object pointed to by both `p1` and `p3` has been ended here `p3->~Foo();` (as `p1` and `p3` both point to the same object).

Comment: When the destructor is called, the object is destroyed, so it's meaningless to set `destructed = true;`, you won't be able to access it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first call to `std::launder` has undefined behavior, because when you call it there is no `Foo` object in its lifetime at the provided address (because `Foo` isn't an implicit-lifetime type). That's a precondition for `std::launder`. You may only do the `std::launder` call after the placement-`new`.

And `p3->destructed == true` has undefined behavior either way, because you ended the lifetime of the `Foo` object with its destructor call. After that you aren't allowed to access the object anymore.